# Using 'Class' and ES6

Tags: mootools

Is there a conflict of behavior for using the Class expression, since it became a reserved word in the latest version of Ecmascript? Can't say if there is identity of grammar between the two contexts, but I guess the built-in noun takes precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. Its `class` keyword and MooTools' [`Class`](https://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Class/Class) identifier don't conflict at all.

If you mean the "classes" generated, I wouldn't try to use one style to subclass a "class" created with the other style (though you might get it to work, particularly if using `class` to subclass a `Class` class), but other than that, there's no big conflict. They both create objects with associated prototypes.